# How do I use the "like" operator in Crystal Reports 2008 using a parameter

Tags: crystal-reports, formula, sql-like, crystal-reports-2008

I am trying to create a formula based on a parameter that will allow the user to select a description of a supply item, or if none is selected to pull all values.  Also want to be able to give them a parameter that allows them to type any part of the description using the "like" option.  I can get the first part of the formula to work but not the second part.  It is correctly pulling a typed in item or if none is typed it returns all values.   Anything past the first "or" does not work.  Should I create a separate parameter for the second part or can I use the same one?

```
IF HASVALUE ({?DESCR}) THEN{Command.DESCRIPTION} = {?DESCR} else true
or 
  ( UPPER({Command.DESCRIPTION}) LIKE "*" + UPPERCASE({?DESCR}) + "*") 
  OR 
  ( UPPER({Command.DESCRIPTION}) LIKE "*" + UPPERCASE({?DESCR}) + "*")
```

Answer (score 1):

To the extent I understand your requirement you don't need anything after the `if` because though you give single character or a string your `HASVALUE ({?DESCR})` returns true... hence you can modify your formula as

```
IF HASVALUE ({?DESCR}) 
THEN{Command.DESCRIPTION} LIKE "*" + {?DESCR} + "*"
else true
```

you can use `UPPERCASE` if you need.

Edit:

```
 IF HASVALUE ({?DESCR}) 
THEN {Command.DESCRIPTION} LIKE "*" + {?DESCR} + "*" 
ELSE IF HASVALUE({?NIIN}) 
THEN {Command.NIIN} = {?NIIN} 
ELSE IF HASVALUE({?CLASS}) 
THEN {Command.CLASS} = {?CLASS} 
else TRUE
```

Comment: If I have several optional varibles for the formula to look at how would I write this to include them all? Would I use else if or OR? I entered this and it did not come back with an error however when prompted I don't get the one item. I think that has something to do with the other parameters. Here is my record select formula:                                                           IF HASVALUE ({?DESCR}) 
THEN{Command.DESCRIPTION} LIKE "*" + {?DESCR} + "*"
ELSE IF 
HASVALUE({?NIIN}) THEN {Command.NIIN} = {?NIIN} 
ELSE IF 
HASVALUE({?CLASS}) THEN {Command.CLASS} = {?CLASS}

else TRUE

Comment: your record selection formula is correct but a small change I have added it in my answer.. check and let me know

Comment: Done.  Let me know if I am not making sense.

Comment: Are you able to get the data

Comment: Thanks Siva,  However, it is not pulling based on what I have entered in the prompt "BAG*" It still pulls all values.

Comment: This means all conditions are failing... try to place parameters in design and check values